# Ubuntu One does not download files on Windows XP

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, windows-xp

I just created my Ubuntu One account on the machine running Ubuntu
and it works flawless. Then I tried to access the same account from my XP machine.
I can access account, and see all files, but when I try to access or download, it 
loads and loads, and loads, but nothing happens. Why is that? If I can access the account from a different machine I should be able to download, right?
Please enlighten me.
Thanks in advance. 
Apple314

Comment: Does your Windows XP machine have Service Pack 3, [Windows Installer 4.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4&displaylang=en), and .NET 4 framework installed?

Comment: @Sid it seems like @Apple314 is talking about downloading files from the Web interface

Comment: like @jasonbrooks suggested, which browser did you use?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards